# c++ default parameters

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nonstatic member as a default argument of a nonstatic member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539406/nonstatic-member-as-a-default-argument-of-a-nonstatic-member-function)

Ok. So I'm having problems understanding how to accomplish a seemingly simple task... Here is what I want to accomplish:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
private:
    int _x;
public:
    A(int x){
        _x = x;
    }

    void test(int x=_x){
        cout << x << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a(3);
    a.test();
}
```

The compiler complains about the `int x=_x` part saying `error: invalid use of non-static data member A::_x`

So how do I use a default parameter like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do that.

You can however have an overload for `test` that takes no parameters.

```
void test(){
    test(_x);
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. However if you declare `_x` as static data member as:

```
static int _x; //_x is static data member now!
```

Then you can do that, i.e you can use `_x` as default value for parameters in your member functions.

A nice example from the  C++ Standard itself. Quoting from section §8.3.6/9 :

> Similarly, a nonstatic member shall
>   not be used in a default argument
>   expression, even if it is not
>   evaluated, unless it appears as the
>   id-expression of a class member access
>   expression (5.2.5) or unless it is
>   used to form a pointer to member
>   (5.3.1). [Example: the declaration of
>   X::mem1() in the following example is
>   ill-formed because no object is
>   supplied for the nonstatic member X::a
>   used as an initializer.

```
int b;
class X {
   int a;
   int mem1(int i = a); // error: nonstatic member a used as default argument
   int mem2(int i = b); // OK; use X::b
   static int b;
};
```

> The declaration of X::mem2() is
>   meaningful, however, since no object
>   is needed to access the static member
>   X::b.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, that example is perfect. I wonder if C++0x (or future versions) going to address any of these kinds of limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Does your function have a sentinel (-1)?

```
void test(int x=-1)
{
    if(x == -1)
        x = _x;

    //Rest of code
}
```

You could also use:

```
void test(int x, bool bUseLocal=false)
{
    if(bUseLocal)
        x = _x;

    //Rest of code
}
```

Comment: What if the argument passed is `-1` itself? You would think no argument is passed and hence would use `_x` instead?

Comment: That's why I asked if there is a sentinel (a never used value).

Comment: Unfortunately I'd like to assume all values are valid.

Comment: Both the approaches above are solid (Daniel/Nawaz); I've added a second option to mine as well.  I like Daniel's the best though.