# "default argument missing for parameter" compiler error

Tags: c++, g++, default-arguments

```cpp
void func ( string word = "hello", int b ) {
    // some jobs
}
```

in another function

```cpp
//calling 
func ( "", 10 ) ;
```

When I compile, it emits this error:

> default argument missing for parameter

I want to use that function like `func ( 10 )` or `func ( "hi" )`.

How can I fix it without changing anything, such as setting `int b = 0`?

Comment: Are you trying to do this : [Default argument in the middle of parameter list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637679/default-argument-in-the-middle-of-parameter-list)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can't have non-default parameters *after* your default parameters begin. Put another way, how would you specify a value for `b` leaving `word` to the default of "hello" ?

Answer (score 37):

The arguments with a default value have to come in the end of the argument list.

So just change your function declaration to

```
void func(int b, string word = "hello")
```

Answer (score 15):

Parameters with default values have to come at the end of the list because, when calling the function, you can leave arguments off the end, but can't miss them out in the middle.

Since your arguments have different types, you can get the same effect using an overload:

```
void func ( string word, int b ) {

  // some jobs

}

void func ( int b ) { func("hello", b); }
```

Answer (score 9):

The error message is proper. If the default argument is assigned to a given parameter then all subsequent parameters should have a default argument. You can fix it in 2 ways;

(1) change the order of the argument:

```
void func (int b, string word = "hello");
```

(2) Assign a default value to `b`:

```
void func (string word = "hello", int b = 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot fix it without changing anything!

To fix it, you can use overloading:

```
void func ( string word, int b ) {
  // some jobs
}

void func ( string word ) {
    func( word, 999 );
}

void func ( int b ) {
    func( "hello", b );
}
```