# Default constructor defined with default arguments outside the class definition, why does this work? and what happens with templates involved?

Tags: c++, class, templates, default-value, default-constructor

I am aware this is bad form and that default-values should be specified in the declaration, but if you would please indulge me for a moment.. why does this compile? and what is happening exactly?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    test(int n);
};

test::test(int n = 666)
{
    cout << n;
}

int main()
{
    test t;

    cin.sync();
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 666

.. how do templates affect the same piece of code?

```
template <class T>
class test
{
public:
    test(int n);
};

template <class T>
test<T>::test(int n = 666)
{
    cout << n;
}

int main()
{
    test<int> t;

    cin.sync();
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

**Error:** no appropriate default constructor available

Thank you for your time!

Comment: For more default parameter fun: http://ideone.com/mbTJU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the C++ specification specifically allows the first case and disallows the second!

Quote from the C++ spec (§8.3.6/4):

> For non-template functions, default arguments can be added in later declarations of a function in the same scope.

So it looks like for non-template functions, you can indeed introduce the default arguments later on.  No idea why this doesn't work for templates, though!

Comment: Thanks for the C++ spec quote!

Answer (score 1):

The first case is allowed by standard; I remember that was asked by @Johannes and answered by @Nawaz. (Edit: Here is the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637679/default-argument-in-the-middle-of-parameter-list)).

Reason for not allowing the `template` version is because `template` functions are called only when instantiated explicitly. In your case, compiler looks at the declaration as,

```
test<int> t;
```

-->**Edit**: It might differ from compiler to compiler. In gcc [it works fine](http://www.ideone.com/4ATLH).<--

Why it may not work in some compiler **might be** Since you are not explicitly instantiating as `t(N)`, compiler will not be able to resolve `test<T>::test(int n = 666)`. Thus it looks for default constructor with no argument, which is not found; thus resulting in error.

Comment: Although I didnt accept your answer I found it informative, thanks for that.