# Non member function can be declared multiple times while member function can only be declared once?

Tags: c++, member-functions, declare, non-member-functions

Non mumber function can be delcared multiple times while member function can only be declared once? Is this right ? My example seems saying yes.

But Why ?

```
class Base{
public:
    int foo(int i);
    //int foo(int i=10); //error C2535: 'void Base::foo(int)' : member function already defined or declared
};

//but it seems ok to declare it multiple times
int foo(int i);
int foo(int i=10);

int foo(int i)
{
    return i;
}

int main (void)
{
    int i = foo();//i is 10 
}
```

Comment: How does the linker deal with this?

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: A linker matches up actual calls with definitions; it doesn't depend on declarations. The _compiler_ has earlier used those declarations to resolve the calls.

Comment: @all, thanks for all the good answers/comments/links, this matter is now clear !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Standard (2003), §8.3.6/4 says,

> For non-template functions, **default
>   arguments can be added in later
>   declarations of a function** in the same
>   scope.

Example from the Standard itself:

```
void f(int, int);
void f(int, int = 7);
```

The second declaration adds default value!

Also see §8.3.6/6.

And an interesting (and somewhat related) topic:

- [Default argument in the middle of parameter list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637679/default-argument-in-the-middle-of-parameter-list)

And §9.3/2,

> Except for member function definitions that appear outside of a class definition, and except for explicit specializations of member functions of class templates and member function templates (14.7) appearing outside of the class definition, **a member function
>   shall not be redeclared.**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Then isn't that perfect, @James? The quoted part of the standard says it applies to non-template functions.

Comment: @UncleBens: Thanks. That quote is very precise. I added it to my answer. And yeah, after re-reading the question, I felt that the answer seems incomplete and I was looking for another quote from the spec. You did it before me.

Comment: This seems odd to me, is it the linker that adds default arguments in these cases?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: No. It's compiler itself. See this also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637679/default-argument-in-the-middle-of-parameter-list

Comment: @Nawaz There seems to be a theme going, me questioning/adding a side-effect from one of your statements + Johannes - litb having stated the question + your answer before :) I find this quite amusing =) Anyway you have my utmost respect for your knowledge and patience. Thanks.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Honestly, I didn't understand your comment :|

Comment: The one about the linker or the last one about -litb being  ubiquitous to my comments/your answers? Not important. Just thanks.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Of course, the last one.. below my comment in which I gave you a link to Johannes's question and my answer.

Comment: @Nawas I'm trying hard here to just say thanks for your efforts ok!

Answer (score 1):

You get the same result with this simplified version:

```
int foo() ;
int foo() ; // OK -- extern functions may be declared more than once
class C {
  int foo() ;
  int foo() ; // Error -- member function may not be declared more than once
} ;
```

Perhaps the reason is historical -- lots of `C` code used redeclaration of `extern` functions,  so they had to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It certainity works - but I think it is bad practice.