# Reference to Member Variable in Function declaration in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
class FOO {
 void bar(int& var = m_var) {
   // ....
 }
 int m_var;
};
```

Why doesn't this compile? Why didn't they program this into the language? Is there any way to mimic this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nonstatic member as a default argument of a nonstatic member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539406/nonstatic-member-as-a-default-argument-of-a-nonstatic-member-function)

Answer (score 6):

This is not allowed because `m_var` is a member variable and needs to be accessed through the object.
It would **[compile successfully](http://www.ideone.com/r3Bmq)** if `m_var` was a static member of the class.

A simple workaround is calling an overloaded function with same name or another member function through `bar()` (which is a member function & has access to `m_var`) and pass `m_var` as an parameter by reference.It will have the same effect you want to achieve.

Comment: @AIs - this is little confusing, because you are able to access m_var from inside the function. e.g. void bar (int& var) { cout << m_var; }. Looks like this allowed because bar is a non-static member function and can only be called using an object of FOO. The same reasoning applies to above defintion too, right?? so, why does compiler complain about accessing a non-static member directly.

Comment: @srikrish: When you access a member variable, say `membervar` inside a non static member function, it is actually performing `this->membervar`. This is passed as an implicit parameter to every member function.

Comment: @AIs - so why cannot compiler do the same for accessing m_bar in function arguments..Again bar is called using an object of FOO, so this pointer is available. As Alexandre pointed out, it looks like a compiler limitation. Although, I'm thinking what would the purpose of such usage be?

Comment: @srikrish: The order in which the function arguments are passed to an function is **not specfied**. So, even if `this` is passed to function as an implicit parameter, One cannot access `this` in function arguments without invoking unspecifed & hence undefined behavior. Eventually, `this` is not accessible in function arguments for this very reason.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, this is a limitation of the language. It can be implemented into compilers (in my humble opinion) with no difficulty.

If you want this behaviour, you have to write:

```
class FOO 
{
    void bar(int& var) { ... }
    void bar() { this->bar(m_var); }

    int m_var;
};
```

and the extra function call will be inlined by any half-decent compiler, in case you worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to to have static-variables, that would act as placeholders:

```
 class FOO 
    {
    private:
        static int _ph_m_var;
        void bar(int& var = _ph_var)
        {
              if(&var == &_ph_var) { // Default }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare m_var to be a static const. It will compile and run.

static const int m_var should do the trick